# How prove $\mathbb Q$ is close in the following metric space?

Tags: analysis

assume $(d,\mathbb R)$  be a mertic space such that  $$d:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$$$$d(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if x=y} \\
max\{|x|,|y|\}, & \text{if x$\neq$y}  \\
\end{cases}$$
How prove $\mathbb Q$ is close in this metric space and $\mathbb Q$ is not open in this metric space?

Thanks for any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For any $x\in\Bbb R$ and $\epsilon>0$, the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centred at $x$ is

$$\begin{align*}
B(x,\epsilon)&=\{y\in\Bbb R:d(x,y)<\epsilon\}\\
&=\big\{y\in\Bbb R:y=x\text{ or }\max\{|x|,|y|\}<\epsilon\big\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now $\max\{|x|,|y|\}\ge|x|$, so if $x\ne 0$, and $\epsilon\le|x|$, then $\max\{|x|,|y|\}\ge|x|\ge\epsilon$ for **any** $y\ne x$, and therefor $B(x,\epsilon)=\{x\}$. In other words, every non-zero real number is an isolated point in this space. To show that $\Bbb Q$ is closed, just use the fact that $0$ is rational.

To show that $\Bbb Q$ is not open, determine exactly what $B(0,\epsilon)$ looks like for $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\Bbb Q$.

If $x\in\overline{A}\setminus A$, there's a sequence $(a_n)\subseteq A$ with
$$a_n\to x$$
$$\Rightarrow 0<d(a_n,x)\to0$$
$$\Rightarrow|x|\le d(a_n,x)\to0$$
$$\Rightarrow x=0$$
a contradiction.

$A$ can be any set of real numbers not containing $0$.